# insertar datos desde un formulario php a una base de datos

Tags: php, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario a través del cual metes unos datos y estos se deben insertar en la base de datos, pero cuando le doy a enviar me sale:

> undefined index:id (para todos id, descripción,...)

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

datos conexión es donde tengo

```
<?php
$dsn="mysql:dbname=ejemplo9;host=localhost";
$usuario=...
$contrasena=...
?>
```

El código php es este:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

include("datosconexion.php");

     $id=$_POST['id'];
    $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
    $pvp=$_POST['pvp'];
    $stock=$_POST['stock'];


    $consulta="INSERT INTO articulo
                (id,descripcion,pvp,stock) VALUES('$id','$descripcion,'$pvp','$stock')";

    if(mysqli_query($link,$consulta)){
echo " Datos insertados";
    }else{
        echo "Datos NO insertados";

    }
?>

      </body>
</html>
```

Formulario:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="conexionagregar5.php">
      <p>Ingresa los datos</p>
      <p>Escribe el identificador del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name "id_articulo">
      <p>Escribe la descripcion del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name "descripcion">
      <p>Escribe el precio del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name "pvp">
      <p>Escribe si hay stock del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name "stock">
      <input type="submit" value="Guardar datos" name="Enviar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2 dudas, la primera donde esta declarado tu método de conexión y la segunda, si tu id es auto incremental por que lo declaras en tu query?

Comment: Pon el código de tu formulario también para saber si los $_POST realmente capturan lo que envías.

Comment: El formulario:<html><body><form method="post" action="conexionagregar5.php">
  <p>Ingresa los datos</p>
      <p>Escribe el identificador del articulo</p>
         <input type="text" name "id_articulo" >         
        <p>Escribe la descripcion del articulo</p>
        <input type="text" name "descripcion" >   
        <p>Escribe el precio del articulo</p>
        <input type="text" name "pvp" > 
        <p>Escribe si hay stock del articulo</p>
        <input type="text" name "stock" >
         <input type="submit" value="Guardar datos" name="Enviar"> 
    </form> </body></html>

Comment: Si el id es autoincremental

Comment: hola @Maria si el id es auto incremental no lo mandes llamar ni como columna y menos le asignes un valor con `$id`  pues tu gestor de bd lo hace por ti

Comment: vale , pero aun quitando me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Hola Maria, tienes 2 errores importantes, deberías quitar el id tanto del input como en tu query como te lo explicó @shadow, sin mencionar que no coinciden los name ya que en el form lo llamas "id_articulo" y lo tratas de capturar como "id". Aparte de esto, no estas enviando los valores de tus variables en la consulta ya que están entre comillas. Estas mandando el string "$id", "$descripcion" (donde por cierto falta una comilla. Deberías hacer uso de  [**bind_param**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) para evitar estos errores y por cuestiones de seguridad. Saludos

Comment: Vale gracias, ya lo he cambiado

Comment: cambiado todo he descubierto que mi problema ahora y antes es que no me coge el dato que meto en el formulario. Mi problema esta en $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
$pvp=$_POST['pvp'];
$stock=$_POST['stock'];
$imagen=$_POST['imagen'];

Answer (score 1):

Te falta el signo `=` en el atributo name del formulario.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="conexionagregar5.php">
      <p>Ingresa los datos</p>
      <p>Escribe la descripcion del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name="descripcion">
      <p>Escribe el precio del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name="pvp">
      <p>Escribe si hay stock del articulo</p>
      <input type="text" name="stock">
      <input type="submit" value="Guardar datos" name="Enviar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Además, como te han comentado, si tu ID es AutoIncremental, no debes de asignarle ningún valor. Por lo tanto, tu query sería:

```
$consulta="INSERT INTO articulo (descripcion,pvp,stock) VALUES('$descripcion','$pvp','$stock')";
```

Aparte de esto, hay otras cosillas que deberías mirar. Como por ejemplo, el PVP debería ser `decimal/numeric` y el stock un `boolean` (según veo en el formulario en el campo stock informas si hay o no).